# Insert node between two nodes based on attribute condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i was wondering if there's a jquery (or some other library) function that allows me to insert a node (div) between two other nodes (divs) based on its attribute.

For example:

Lets say i have this html code:

```
<div value=111/>
<div value=222/>
<div value=444/>
```

i want to insert `<div value=333/>` between the 222 and 444 accordingly.

Thanks to all helpers.

Comment: What did you already try? Please add the code and describe how it doesnt work.

Comment: Like [Node.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)?

Comment: @FabianSchöner well, i haven't tried yet because i don't know how. But i did do some research and mostly it's .insertAfter() which doesn't help.

Comment: `jQuery.insertAfter` could infact be helpful, the key problem is identifying the element you want the new one to be inserted after. Have a look at https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/. Those should help u getting the right element to use "insertAfter" with. We will help you debugging / extending your code but you have to come up with something, were not a coding service.

Comment: @ChrisG not sure, it doesn't accept a callback to do the condition.

Comment: @FabianSchöner I never expected sof to be a coding service. Was just looking for a starting point.

Comment: @user9852405 - Callback? Condition?

Comment: @user9852405 so your starting point is: get the correct jquery selector to find `<div value=222/>` and use `insertAfter` to insert the new element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

- obtain desired `div` using `querySelector`
- use `after` method to add new element after the one obtained in the previous step

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent = 'three';

const target = document.querySelector('div[value=two]');

target.after(div);
```

```html
<div value="one">one</div>
<div value="two">two</div>
<div value="three">four</div>
```

To dynamically the find correct spot, you can use `find` method like this.

- find the first element with value bigger than the one you provide
- use `before` method to place the new element before the one from the previous step

```js
const myValue = 333;

const div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent = myValue;

const target = [...document.querySelectorAll('div')]
  .find(v => Number(v.getAttribute('value')) > myValue );

target.before(div);
```

```html
<div value="111">111</div>
<div value="222">222</div>
<div value="444">444</div>
```

Comment: That `[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].filter(...)[0]` is a **really** long way to write `document.querySelector('div[value=two]')`. (Separately: `.filter(...)[0]` is never best practice; instead: `.find(...)`.)

Comment: This is an interesting approach. But take into account that the dom content is being generated dynamically and the vales need to compared by greater or less.

Comment: @user9852405 Check now, it should work for dynamic values.

Comment: Ty. The. find is time consuming, is there a way to do it without searching? Maybe by grabbing the element

Comment: @user9852405 How is it supposed to work if you need a condition to find the element but don't want to search it...? Those two requirements are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @user9852405 But how do you want to grab an element if you don't have a way to target it?

Comment: getElementByClass

Answer (score 0):

Both jQuery offers a variety of methods for this: [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/), [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/), [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/), and [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

The DOM provides [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) and [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

For instance, using jQuery's `before`:

```
$("div[value=444]").before("<div value=333></div>");
```

Or using the DOM's `insertBefore`:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("value", "333");
var target = document.querySelector("div[value=444]");
target.parentNode.insertBefore(div, target);
```

Or using the DOM's `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```
document.querySelector("div[value=444]").insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforebegin",
    "<div value=333></div>"
);
```

---

Side note: [`div`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-div-element) is not a [void element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#void-elements), `<div />` isn't a self-closing tag, it's a [start tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#start-tags) with a `/` in it that's ignored.

Side note 2: `value` is not a valid attribute for [`div`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-div-element) elements.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the html is dynamic and not static, so i need to use a condition before the node is being inserted.

Comment: @user9852405 - You need to provide much more detail in the question, then, we can't guess at what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

use `after();`
here is working example in codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVjbqZ